# How to display / on django site instead of /en/ using i18n_patterns and set_language at the same time?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm using i18n_patterns from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/ but I would like to display the default root / for English (set in `LANGUAGE_CODE` default), instead of `/en/` on my django website.

I tried to use the solid_i18n package but I didn't find out how to make it compatible with `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))`, enabling the user to switch between languagues.

How can I force my `LANGUAGE_CODE` to use the default root `/` url, and still having enabled `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))` using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/views/i18n/#set_language, at the same time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using [django-solid-i18n-urls](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls/blob/master/README.md).

You should have:

```
SOLID_I18N_USE_REDIRECTS = True
```

> In that case, for root paths (without prefix), django will try to discover user preferred language. If it doesn't equal to default language, redirect to path with corresponding prefix will occur. If preferred language is the same as default, then that request path will be processed (without redirect).